# Can not ssh authenticate with remote host using git bash

Tags: ssh

I recently have a new Windows 11 PC, installed latest version of git for windows (git version 2.40.0.windows.1)
I ssh-keygen a key pair, copied the public key to remote host authorized_keys file. but when I do ssh id@remote_host, I get prompt to enter password.

If I do the same in Windows command or Window power shell, it works fine. (no need to enter password).
In my old PC, running git for windows version 2.31.1, ssh in git bash works fine.

What could be the problem with git for windows 2.40.0 ?

Comment: I see Windows 11 has it own ssh in C:\Windows\System32\Openssh,  so probably ssh come with Windows work, but git for Windows ssh latest version does not work